# Date Range not applied to Day book / Voucher Register Report Export in Tally ERP 9 Integration using XML

Tags: xml, datefilter, tally

I am trying to export "Day Book" from Tally for particular period using following XML, but I am getting only data for "Current Date of Tally" not as per given period.

```
<ENVELOPE>
  <HEADER>
     <TALLYREQUEST>Export Data</TALLYREQUEST>
   </HEADER>
<BODY>
   <EXPORTDATA>
      <REQUESTDESC>
         <REPORTNAME>Day Book</REPORTNAME>
         <STATICVARIABLES>
            <SVEXPORTFORMAT>$$SysName:XML</SVEXPORTFORMAT>
             <SVFROMDATE>20171001</SVFROMDATE>
             <SVTODATE>20171030</SVTODATE>
         </STATICVARIABLES>
      </REQUESTDESC>
   </EXPORTDATA>
</BODY>
</ENVELOPE>
```

please suggest changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Change the SVTODATE to 20171031
2. Change the REPORTNAME to Voucher Register

Note that the Tally ERP education version supports the following dates only.
1st of every month
2nd of every month
31st of every month

For Tally XML tags, refer :
[www.rtslink.com](http://www.rtslink.com)

Comment: Life saving x"D i have another version but was developing on educational.